# What is missing in my application.html.erb? RailsCast 209-devise-revised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, railscasts

I was going through RailsCast 209-devise-revised. In that in `application.html.erb` this code is given(changed the paths)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="user_nav">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Logged in as <strong><%=current_user.email %></strong>
        <%= link_to 'Edit_profile',edit_blog_post_path%>
        <%= link_to 'LogOut', destroy_user_session_path%>
        <%else %>
        <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_path %>
        <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
    <% end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

problem is that in RailsCast this file works fine, but for me

`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"blog_posts"} missing required keys: [:id]` error is thrown.

1) How did it work in railscast without giving the `id`?

2) In `application.html.erb` how to I give the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you already accepted the answer, imho the correct answer should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit_profile', edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

Because I would presume you want to edit the user, not a blog-post whose id is accidentally identical to the id of the user.

Comment: Yes, I was facing some issues with the previous answer like you said. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= link_to 'Edit_profile',edit_blog_post_path(current_user.id)%>
```